# vector<X*> vec vs vector<X>* vec

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, vector

What is the difference in memory usage between:

```
std::vector<X*> vec
```

where each element is on the heap, but the vector itself isn't

and

```
std::vector<X>* vec
```

where the vector is declared on the heap, but each element is (on the stack?).

The second option doesn't make much sense- does it mean the vector pointer is on the heap, but it points back at each element, which are on the stack??

Comment: The second means `vec` is a pointer to `std::vector<X>`, and thats *all* you can assume it means. What it points *to* is not determinate based on what you have here. It could just as easily point to an automatic vector as it could a dynamic-allocation (or be outright-indeterminate, which it is right now). And the pointer's location is likewise inconclusive from just this code. It could be a member variable of an object class that is dynamically managed. It could me a local function variable, it could be a global. Context is a beautiful thing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say that in `std::vector<X*> vec` elements are "on the heap"? You mean that you intentionally allocated them on heap? Because by itself `std::vector<X*>` does not mean that elements are "on the heap".

Comment: And that's why the whole "heap" and "stack" terminology is ultimately not very helpful.

Comment: @AndreyT I mean that the pointers contained in the vector point to objects which are on the heap. I am assuming a pointer always points to the heap?

Comment: "a pointer always points to the heap" - no, this is not true. They can point to the stack as well.

Comment: this is wrong assumption. You can use pointers to local variables as well (to stack)

Comment: @user997112: a pointer does not tell you how the object is allocated, it just tells you that at that location there's an object of that type; nothing prevents you from storing pointers to stack-allocated objects, or objects with static storage duration (and there are legitimate use cases for all these uses). It is true, however, that *typically* people store heap-allocated objects in `std::vector<T *>`.

Comment: OTOH `std::unique_ptr` *does* tell you how the object is allocated, and also takes care of automatically deallocating it.

Comment: @user997112: But that's is not true. A pointer can point anywhere in memory. There is absolutely no grounds for assuming that pointers always point to heap. They can easily point to local objects allocated on stack. Pointers point wherever you make them point. No restrictions at all.

Comment: @everyone so if I have a vector<X>* =newv ector<X>(); and I end up adding a lot of X, I am fine because only my heap will grow. However, what about if each of my X objects are variable too? Can I still use vector<X>* rather than vector<X*>*? I am worried about the stack growing because I have a large number of X objects.

Comment: @Ben, so unless I declare something as a local variable in a function, it won't be on the stack?

Comment: @user997112: Correct (well, declared local variables plus use of `_alloca`), and everything that is added to the stack (including `_alloca` blocks) goes away as soon as the function returns.

Comment: @user997112: Allocations on the stack belong to functions in the call stack which have not yet returned. Objects can't (dynamically) allocate from the stack. The stack usage of any local variable is limited to `sizeof (T)`. Any "growing" will need to dynamically allocate memory (typically from a heap, but there are other data structures for memory management).

Comment: Actually, what I meant to say I am worried about is passing a massive vector as an argument to a function and all of the elements are passed on the stack also- that is what worries me...

Comment: You can pass large or expensive-to-copy objects _by reference_ without having to resorting to raw pointers.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<X*> vec
```

Is an array of pointers of the class X. This is useful, for example, when making an array of non-copyable classes/objects like std::fstream in C++98. So

```
std::vector<std::fstream> vec;
```

is WRONG, and won't work. But

```
std::vector<std::fstream*> vec;
```

works, while you have to create a new object for each element, so for example if you want 5 fstream elements you have to write something like

```
vec.resize(5);
for(unsigned long i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    vec[i] = new std::fstream;
}
```

Of course, there are many other uses depending on your application.

Now the second case is a pointer of the vector itself. So:

```
vector<int>* vec;
```

is just a pointer! it doesn't carry any information, and you can't use it unless you create the object for the vector itself, like

```
vec = new vector<int>();
```

and eventually you may use it as:

```
vec->resize(5);
```

Now this is not really useful, since vectors anyway store their data on the heap and manage the memory they carry. So use it only if you have a good reason to do it, and sometimes you would need it. I don't have any example in mind on how it could be useful.

Comment: I think you mean C++98 -- there is no such thing as C++99.  You should note that the above limitations on streams are NOT true in C++11, as streams are movable.

Comment: But your edit, which says they are copyable, is wrong.  Your original statement that they are non-copyable was fine, and remains true in C++11 and C++1y.

Comment: @BenVoigt Really? I thought they're copyable in C++11! are you sure?

Comment: @Samer: The `ios_base` copy constructor is deleted.  The streams now have *move* constructors, which is what Chris said, and that allows them to be placed in containers, but still cannot be copied.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you really asked:

```
vector<X>* vec = new vector<X>();
```

it means that the whole vector with all its elements is on the heap. The elements occupy a contiguous memory block on the heap.

Comment: Except the vector is not "with all its elements".  They aren't stored together, instead vector holds a pointer to its elements, and even `vector<X> vec;` will have the elements stored in a contiguous memory block on the heap (with possible exception for very small capacity).

Answer (score 0):

The difference is where (and what) you need to do for manual memory management.

Whenever you have a raw C-style pointer in C++, you need to do some manual memory management -- the raw pointer can point at anything, and the compiler won't do any automatic construction or destruction for you.  So you need to be aware of where the pointer points and who 'owns' the memory pointed at in the rest of your code.

So when you have

```
std::vector<X*> vec;
```

you don't need to worry about memory management for the vector itself (the compiler will do it for you), but you do need to worry about the memory management of the pointed at `X` objects for the pointers you put in the vector.  If you're allocating them with `new`, you need to make sure to manually `delete` them at some point.

When you have

```
std::vector<X> *vec;
```

You DO need to worry about memory management for the vector itself, but you DON'T need to worry about memory management for the individual elements.

Simplest is if you have:

```
std::vector<X> vec;
```

then you don't need to worry about memory management at all -- the compiler will take care of it for you.

Answer (score 0):

In code using good modern C++ style, *none of the above is true*.

`std::vector<X*>` is a collection of handles to objects of type `X` or any of its subclasses, which you do not own.  The owner knows how they were allocated and will deallocate them -- you don't know and *don't care*.

`std::vector<X>*` would in practice, only ever be used as a function argument which represents a vector you do not own (the caller does) but which you are going to modify.  According to one common approach, the fact that it's a pointer rather than a vector means that it is optional.  Much more rarely it might be used as a class member where the lifetime of the attached vector is known to outlive the class pointing to it.

`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X>>` is a polymorphic collection of mixed objects of various subclasses of `X` (and maybe `X` itself directly).  Occasionally you might use it non-polymorphically if `X` is expensive to move, but modern style makes most types cheap to move.

Prior to C++11, `std::vector<some_smart_pointer<X> >` (yes, there's a space between the closing brackets) would be used for both the polymorphic case and the non-copyable case.  Note that `some_smart_pointer` isn't `std::unique_ptr`, which didn't exist yet, not `std::auto_ptr`, which wasn't usable in collections.  `boost::unique_ptr` was a good choice.  With C++11, the copyability requirement for collection elements is relaxed to moveability, so this reason completely went away. (There remain some types which are neither copyable nor moveable, such as the ScopeGuard pattern, but these should not be stored in a collection anyway)